# How to split binary number in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, function, split

I decided to write program, where user enter a binary number like this `11000000.10101000` and then it converts into a number. But I don't know why the output is only a last number. This is my code:

```
function ConvertToDec()
            {
                var binaryNumber = document.getElementById('NumberInput').value;
                var decNumber;
                var split = binaryNumber.split("\.");
                for(i=0; i<split.length; i++) {
                    decNumber = parseInt(split[i], 2);
                    //console.log(split[i]);
                    //console.log(decNumber);
                    document.getElementById('Result').value = decNumber;
                }
                
            }
```

Comment: what is the dot for? a decimal separator? or just to separate two independent strings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every iteration is re-initializing the variable `decNumber`, you need to store the converted value, then outside of that `for-loop` assign the result to the input.

*Important*: if you have multiple dots, multiple numbers will be converted, i.e: `1111.01010.10101 = number.number.number`.

```js
function ConvertToDec() {
  var binaryNumber = "11000000.10101000";
  //var binaryNumber = document.getElementById('NumberInput').value;
  var decNumber;
  var split = binaryNumber.split("\.");
  var result = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < split.length; i++) {
    decNumber = parseInt(split[i], 2);
    //console.log(split[i]);
    //console.log(decNumber);    
    result += (result === '' ? '' : '.') + decNumber;
  }
  document.getElementById('Result').value = result;
}

ConvertToDec();
```

```html
<input id='Result' value=''>
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the dot is a decimal separator, then you could convert the integer part with `parseInt` and with `radix` of `2` to a decimal value and convert the fraction part to a number by taking a fraction of the base of two.

> ```
> binary             decimal (2^n)    n
> -----------------  -------------  ----
> 11000000.10101000
> 10000000           128              7
>  1000000            64              5
>         .1            .5           -1
>         .001          .125         -3
>         .00001        .03125       -5
> -----------------  -------------
> 11000000.10101000  192.65625
> ```

```js
function bin2dec(bin) {
    var [int, frac] = bin.split("\.");

    return [...frac].reduce((d, b, i) => d + b / (2 << i), parseInt(int, 2));
}

console.log(bin2dec('11000000.10101000'));
```

Answer (score 0):

For each iteration decNumber gets a new value assigned. You could store the result as a string and concatenate every iteration.